# Prototype: Detect Chrome and Add Class

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, prototypejs, browser-detection

Okay, I have a jQuery line of code, that I need to convert to work with Prototype.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')!=-1)
 {
  /* Applying a special chrome curosor,
   as it fails to render completely blank curosrs. */
  zoom.addClass('chrome');  
 }
});
```

zoom is the classname and I want to add the class chrome to it if chrome is detected.

So far for Prototype I have this:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
 Object.prototype.addClass = function(className) {
    if (!this.hasClass(className)) { //if the class isn't there already
    this.className += (' ' + className); //append it to the end of the class list
    }
 }
});
```

But unfortunately, that's as far as I can get with Google searching.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by *zoom is the classname*. Are you saying that's a jQuery object containing an element that has the class `"zoom"`?

Comment: This has already been answered in a post below. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you're selecting elements with the class `"zoom"`.

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')!=-1) {
        $$('.zoom').each(function(e) {
            e.addClassName( 'chrome' );
        });
    }
});
```

In the code in the question, you're adding to `Object.prototype`. Never do that. It will only cause problems.

Comment: You can reduce some of that indentation with `$$('.zoom').invoke('addClassName', 'chrome');`